# A game on equiangular polygons

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $n\geq 3$ be a natural number and  Consider the following game:

Correspond an integer to each vertices of an equiangular polygon 
(at least two of the numbers are unequal).

**(1) Replace the number of each vertices with the number obtained by the sum of 
its neighborhood numbers minus its own number. (Edit: Do this for all vertices at once, not one by one)**

This gives us a new equiangular polygon with an integer corresponded to each of its vertices.

Again do as in (1) and Continue the progress.

Let $A$ be the set containing the numbers corresponded to vertices of this polygon
in this (infinite) process. Now the question is:

**what are the possible values of $n$ if we want $A$  to be a bounded set of integers!?**

Comment: Voted up because its a nice problem. But is it a problem for MO??

Comment: Could you clarify -- is (1) done on a vertex-by-vertex basis or "all vertices at once"? (I assume the latter)

Comment: What role does the equiangularness of the polygon play? Would the question be the same for a cycle of numbers with the same replacement rule?

Comment: Why the 'teaching' tag for this question?

Comment: If $n$ is even, an alternating string of plus and minus $1$s becomes an alternating string of plus and minus $3$s, then $9$s, $27$s, etc.  (This assumes "neighborhood numbers" means the two adjacent numbers, and also that all vertices are done at once, as J.J. Green commented.)  So there's "half" an answer....

Comment: A more specific question: What is a nonconstant starting sequence that leads to $|A|$ finite?

Comment: @J. J. Green: do all vertices at once.

Comment: @Joseph: Of course you can assume that cyclic form of problem.

Comment: @Barry--perhaps only a "quarter" of an answer: you need $n$ to be even.

Comment: @Sally, it's rather a solitary game.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz, you're quite right.

Comment: The sequence $(1,2,3,2)$ goes to $(3,2,1,2)$ and then back to  $(1,2,3,2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $n$ there is always a (certainly non-constant) initial choice of integer labels $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of the vertices of the $n$-gone for which the set of numbers $A$ is unbounded.

The question is more subtle if you ask for which $n$ it is possible to find a  non-constant  integer choice of labels for which the set of numbers $A$ is bounded. The  answer is then: it is possible if and only if $n$ is either a multiple of $4$ or a multiple of $6$.
$$ *$$

The iteration you consider is described by a simple symmetric [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $L$ of order $n$  (in the notation of the link, the non-zero coefficients are $c_0=-1$, $c_1=c_{n-1}=1$). It has therefore $n$ real eigenvalues (repeated according to their multiplicity, which is either $1$ or $2$)
$$\lambda_k=2\cos(2\pi k/n) -1,\qquad k=1,\dots, n\ . $$

In particular, the spectral radius of $L$ is larger than $1$, corresponding to $\lambda_{ \lfloor n/2\rfloor} $ . Since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ spans linearly $\mathbb{R}^n$, some element $v$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ must have a non-zero component w.r.to $\lambda_{ \lfloor n/2\rfloor} $ in the spectral decomposition, implying that $A=\{L^k v\}_{k\ge0}$ is unbounded. Note that $v$ is certainly  not a constant vector, as required. Also note that for even $n$, $\lambda_{n/2}=-3$ corresponds to the  example in Barry Cipra's comment.

For what $n$ it is possible to find non-constant integer labels $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of the vertices for which $A=\{L^k v\}_{k\ge0}$ is bounded? This is certainly the case if $n$ is a multiple of $4$: then we have the eigenvector $(1,0,-1,0,\dots)$ of the eigenvalue  $-1$.
If $n$ is a multiple of $6$, $L$ is singular with a $2$ dimensional kernel spanned by the $6$-periodic vectors $(1,0,-1,-1,0,1,\dots)$ and  $(1,1,-1,-1,1,1,\dots)$. Of course these generate bounded orbits.

Conversely, assume that $n$ is such that there exists a non-constant $v\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ 
that generates a bounded orbit $\{L^k v\}_k $ . If $L$ is singular, $n$ must be a multiple of $6$, as it follows from the above expression for the eigenvalues. If $L$ is not singular the orbit $\{L^k v\}_k $ is periodic, that is, $L^m v = v$  for some $m$. So $1$ is one of the eigenvalues of $L^m$, which are of the form  $\lambda_k^m$, and this is only possible if $\lambda_k=-1$ or  $\lambda_k=1$. In the former case, $k=0$ and $v$ is a  simple eigenvalue of $L$ with constant coordinates, which is not the case. In the latter case, $\cos(2\pi k/n)=0$, which implies that $n=4k$.

Comment: If $A$ stays bounded, you'll wind up *repeating* things, which requires eigenvalues that are roots of unity.  Doesn't this pretty much finish things?

Comment: Indeed, I was editing to elaborate on this point. So everything reduces to checking when 0, 1, or -1 is an eigenvalue of L.

Comment: @Pietro: Please explain two parts: whay "$\Bbb{Z}^n$ spans linearly $\Bbb{R}^n$" ? and in the last paragraph, when $L$ is singular how do you conclude that $6 | n$ ?

Comment: @Sally: The first statement just means that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is not contained in any proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (in particular, it is not contained in the eigenspace of all eigenvalues less than 1 in absolute value). Second statement: $L$ is singular iff $\lambda_k=0$ for some $1\le k \le n$, that is $\cos(2\pi k/n)=1/2$, so $n=6k$ or $5n=6k$.